# Reasons for a different interpretation of a python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, luigi, interpretation

What are the possible reasons for a different interpretation of a given python code?

I have a code which I can execute with no errors on a computer, but which outputs errors on another one.
The python versions are the same (2.7.12).
The encoding of the scripts are the same.
I wonder what could explain this because these are the only two reasons I see for a different code interpretation.

Here is what the code looks like, using luigi (here is only a part of the code) :

```
class ExampleClass(luigi.postgres.CopyToTable):

    def rows(self):
        """
        Return/yield tuples or lists corresponding to each row to be inserted.
        """
        with self.input()['Data'].open('r') as fobj:
            for line in fobj:
                yield line.strip('\n').split('\t')
```

When I run the whole code on the computer where i do have an error (which is caused by the lines I wrote above), I get this :

```
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

And there is, indeed, a mix of spaces and tabs in the code.
It is easy to solve, no problem here, but my question is about :
What could explain that difference in the interpretation?

Comment: Can you post the errors observed after replacing all the spaces with tabs?

Comment: What is your transfer method of said code?

Comment: the answer is your error message: indentation. So you can fix it by yourself.

Comment: @JasonD I simply use the very same code I stored on github. So to transfer the code i download it from github.

Comment: Don't post code in comments; it's virtually unreadable. Add it to your question.

Comment: "The python versions are the same (2.7.12)." - no, they definitely were not. It would be completely impossible for the kind of "interpretation" you have in mind to happen with the same Python version on the same code, but trivial to see a different result with a different Python version. But also, "unexpected indent" is not a plausible message for this code, because every line shown is *supposed to be* indented one more level from the previous.

Comment: You said "And there is, indeed, a mix of spaces and tabs in the code.", but in the actual post source for the original revision of the question, the code uses only tabs.

Answer (score -1):

As the error says

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: malformed \N character escape

The line in question is this one:

> cursor.copy_expert('copy ' + self.table + ' from stdin with header csv delimiter \'' + self.column_separator + '\' null \'''\\N''\' quote \'''\"''\' ', file)

Your "N" should be lowercase otherwise it doesn't count as a newline character. Try this:

```
cursor.copy_expert('copy ' + self.table + ' from stdin with header csv delimiter \'' + self.column_separator + '\' null \'''\\\n''\' quote \'''\"''\' ', file)
```

Comment: As I explained in the post, this is not about solving this error, this is about understanding why this code works on another computer (because it DOES work), and not on this computer. I only gave the errors reports and the codes to help understand.

Comment: That code definitely does not work on any computer. But yes, it's unrelated to the question that was actually asked - which is why it should not have been included in the question in the first place, and why I edited it out.